# Initiate multiple file select without click and hold - Android Cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova, mobile, mobile-application

I'm building a Cordova app and updated the onShowFileChooser method in SystemWebChromeClient.java to allow selecting multiple files.  The problem is, to select multiple files, you have to click and hold on the first file to initiate the multi-select.  What I need it to do is to allow multiple file select without having to click and hold the first file.  I'd like to be able to do this without an additional plugin if possible.

Here's the HTML for the multiple file select:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" accept="image/*,video/*" multiple />
```

And here's the Java code for the multiple file select:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, final ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathsCallback, final WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
    Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    try {
        parentEngine.cordova.startActivityForResult(new CordovaPlugin() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
                Uri[] result = WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent);

                if (result == null) {
                    ClipData clipData = intent.getClipData();
                    result = new Uri[clipData.getItemCount()];

                    for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                        result[i] = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    }
                }

                filePathsCallback.onReceiveValue(result);
            }
        }, intent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        LOG.w("No activity found to handle file chooser intent.", e);
        filePathsCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
    }
    return true;
}
```

This issue only happens in Android, not iOS.

Using Cordova version 8.1.2 and Android platform 7.1.1.

Thanks in advance!